# Необходимо найти значение в столбце 'num_sensor' (>1), определить по 'id-sensor' последнюю строку и из нее получить значение 'num_cell'

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```java
public ResultSet numCellInSensor(Sensor numSensor) {
    ResultSet resSet = null;
    String numSENSOR = sensor.getSensor_number();

    String select = "SELECT 'num_sensor', MAX('id-sensor'),'num_cell' 
FROM my_table 
WHERE 'num_sensor' = " + numSENSOR + 
" GROUP BY 'num_sensor','num_cell' HAVING MAX('id-sensor')";

    try {
        PreparedStatement prSt = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(select);
        resSet = prSt.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resSet;
}
```

При выполнении запроса в цикл попадают все номера, а нужно чтобы попадала последняя запись.

Comment: Что-то код ну никак не бьётся с задачей в заголовке темы...

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста. Я не так давно в теме, но более простые запросы уже делал. И они получались.

Comment: Задача в заголовке темы однозначно предполагает, что из всей таблицы будет выбрана только одна запись (или ни одной, если записей с `num_sensor > 1` не имеется). А вот запрос предполагает кучу записей, по одной для каждой пары (num_sensor, num_cell).

Comment: Так и есть. Получить необходимо только одну запись, а запрос нужно сформировать таким образом, чтобы запись осталась одна(последняя). Вопрос как раз-таки в запросе: можно ли его сделать таким, чтобы запись была единственной?

Comment: @Nowhere Man, огромное человеческое спасибо! Все работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выбрать одну подходящую строку без группировки:

- отфильтровать значения по полю `num_sensor` в части `WHERE`
- отсортировать по полю `id-sensor` по убыванию, чтобы первым оказалось максимальное значение при помощи `ORDER BY`
- выбрать единственную подходящую строку при помощи `LIMIT 1`

Тогда метод `getData` вернёт пустой экземпляр `Optional`, если подходящие данные не будут найдены или же обёртку с требуемым значением `num_cell`.

```java
private static final String SQL = """
SELECT `num_cell`, `id-sensor`
FROM my_table
WHERE `num_sensor` = ?
ORDER BY `id-sensor` DESC
LIMIT 1
""";

public static Optional<Object> getData(Object numPerson, Connection conn) {
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL)) {
        ps.setObject(1, numPerson);
        ResultSet set = ps.executeQuery();
        return set.next() 
            ? Optional.of(set.getObject("num_cell")) 
            : Optional.empty(); 
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Ошибка выполнения запроса: " + SQL 
            + "; numPerson= " + numPerson, e);
    }
}
```

Разумеется, вернуть можно любой другой требуемый объект с полями, а не только одно значение `num_cell`.

Comment: Я добавил полный код. После обращения к этому методу, хотелось бы получить запрос к БД,  после которого  цикл давал бы 1 вариант.

Comment: В данном решении и будет гарантированно возвращаться одна строка, цикл не нужен, достаточно _одной_ проверки условия `set.next()`